# What are the benefits of the permission policy update on Android 8.0 and above?

Tags: android, permissions, android-security

Android has slightly changed their permission policies on Android 8.0:

> Prior to Android 8.0 (API level 26), if an app requested a permission
>   at runtime and the permission was granted, the system also incorrectly
>   granted the app the rest of the permissions that belonged to the same
>   permission group, and that were registered in the manifest.
>
> For apps targeting Android 8.0, this behavior has been corrected. The
>   app is granted only the permissions it has explicitly requested.
>   However, once the user grants a permission to the app, all subsequent
>   requests for permissions in that permission group are automatically
>   granted.
>
> For example, suppose an app lists both READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and
>   WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in its manifest. The app requests
>   READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and the user grants it. If the app targets API
>   level 25 or lower, the system also grants WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE at
>   the same time, because it belongs to the same STORAGE permission group
>   and is also registered in the manifest. If the app targets Android 8.0
>   (API level 26), the system grants only READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE at that
>   time; however, if the app later requests WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, the
>   system immediately grants that privilege without prompting the user.

What is the benefit of such change? It seems they achieve the same purpose. What could go wrong with the previous approach that the new one fixes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What could go wrong with the previous approach that the new one fixes?

Well, you see, there was this bug...

Quoting [the research paper](https://www.ndss-symposium.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/02/ndss2018_08-4_Tuncay_paper.pdf), with emphasis added:

> First,  the  adversary  creates  an  app  that
>   includes  in  its  manifest  file  a  custom  permission  declaration
>   with the protection level
>   `normal`
>   or
>   `signature`
>   and sets this
>   custom permission to be a part of a system permission group
>   (e.g.,  storage,  camera  etc.).  Then,  they  update  the  definition
>   of  this  custom  permission  so  that  the  protection  level  is
>   changed  to
>   `dangerous`
>   and  proceed  to  push  an  update  to
>   their app on the respective app market... The expectation is
>   that since the custom permission is of level
>   `dangerous`, the
>   user will be prompted at runtime to make a decision on whether
>   to  grant  or  deny  this  permission  in  the  runtime  permission
>   model. However, the malicious app automatically gets granted
>   the  permission.  In  addition,  since  the  runtime  permission
>   model grants `dangerous` permissions on a group basis, **the app
>   also  automatically  obtains  all  the  other  requested  dangerous
>   permissions  of  the  system  permission  group  that  the  original
>   permission  belongs  to**.  Same  procedure  can  be  followed  to
>   attack
>   any
>   system permissions group; hence, the adversary can
>   silently obtain
>   all
>   system permissions simultaneously. Requesting dangerous permissions in the Android manifest constitutes
>   no problems for the adversary, as permission requirements of
>   an app are not directly presented to users at installation since
>   Android 6.0. Hence, the user will be completely unaware that
>   all these system permissions are granted to the app.

AFAICT, this Android 8.0 change was part of the mitigation strategy for this bug. This would only help a bit, and so I assume that other changes were made as well. However, given the nature of the bug presented in the paper and the nature of this Android 8.0, I have to assume that the two are at least somewhat related.

Comment: I still don't fully get the improvement made by Android with that policy change. Granting the dangerous permissions automatically and immediately [Android 6.0] or automatically as soon as they are needed [Android 8.0] for me is no improvement [at all] under a security point of view. Sooner or later you will eventually get the second permission too [e.g. WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE] and silently in both the situations. IMHO strange patch, really. The article is very informative, very nice link. But I don't understand where this change comes handy in thwarting any of the attacks presented